# Отличие using от typedef

Tags: c++, c++11

Какие есть отличия `using` от `typedef` кроме того, что `using` работает с шаблонами? Если только в этом, то почему нельзя было добавить эту поддержку в `typedef`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Директива `using` существует только в `С++`, `typedef` - это наследство от чистого `C`, в нём нет шаблонов.

Тем более что они отличаются по своей сути. При использовании `typedef` мы создаём синоним имени типа, а `using` позволяет создать синоним типа, либо включить в текущее пространство имён существующее.

Comment: т.е. это на уровне фатального недостатка? 

Всегда думал, что typedef создает новый typeid, а сейчас ввел следующее:
http://ideone.com/KAW340

Comment: обновил ответ, `typedef` задаёт **синоним** имени

Comment: Пространства имен тут вообще ни к месту, т.к. `using` как замена `typedef` это не тот случай, что `using` - декларация или директива.

Answer (score 8):

`using` позволяет писать более красивый код и позволяет избавиться от наследия `typedef`, который имеет в своём имени `def`, который может подразумевать `definition`, которого на самом деле не происходит. `using` это замена `typedef` с некоторыми добавками, каких `typedef` не имеет. В современном коде использовать `typedef` нет никакого смысла.

Более подробно о том, что думают об этом те, кто предложили это изменение в стандарт, а также об истории `using` можно почитать на английской части [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24916435/why-do-type-aliases-in-c-use-using-instead-of-typedef-in-their-syntax).

Answer (score 7):

Еще одно удобство `using` по сравнению с `typedef` можно увидеть на примере указателя на функцию (аргумент int, возвращает float):

```
typedef float (*func_ptr)(int);
using func_ptr = float (*)(int);
```

Это дело вкуса, но мне по душе больше второй вариант.

*Вычитано у Скотта Майерса*

Answer (score 4):

Я бы сказал так - главное преимущество `using` перед `typedef` - при работе с шаблонами. В частности, объявления псевдонимов могут быть шаблонизированы (и в этом случае они называются шаблонами псевдонимов), в то время как `typedef` — нет. Это дает программистам на C++11 простой механизм для выражения того, что в C++98 можно было выразить только хакерскими способами, с помощью `typedef`, вложенных в шаблонные `struct`. Рассмотрим, например, определение синонима для связанного списка, который использует пользовательский распределитель памяти `MyAlloc`. В случае шаблонов псевдонимов это просто:

```
// MyAllocList<T> является синонимом для std::list<T,MyAlloc<T>>:
template<typename T>
    using MyAllocList = std::list<T, MyAlloc<T>>;

MyAllocList<Widget> lw;    // Клиентский код
```

В случае typedef приходится идти длинным окружным путем:

```
// MyAllocList<T>::type — синоним для std::list<T,MyAlloc<T>>:
template<typename T>
struct MyAllocList {
    typedef std::list<T, MyAlloc<T>> type;
};

MyAllocList<Widget>::type lw; // Клиентский код
```

Все еще хуже. Если вы хотите использовать `typedef` в шаблоне для создания связанного списка, хранящего объекты типа, указанного параметром шаблона, имя, указанное в `typedef`, следует предварять ключевым словом `typename`:

```
template<typename T>
class Widget {                          // Widget<T> содержит
private:                                // MyAllocList<T>,
    typename MyAllocList<T>::type list; // как член-данные
    …
};
```

Здесь `MyAllocList<T>::type` ссылается на тип, который зависит от параметра типа шаблона (`T`). Тем самым `MyAllocList<T>::type` является зависимым типом, а одно из правил C++ требует, чтобы имена зависимых типов предварялись ключевым словом `typename`.
Если `MyAllocList` определен как шаблон псевдонима, это требование использования ключевого слова `typename` убирается (как и громоздкий суффикс “`::type`”):

```
template<typename T>
using MyAllocList = std::list<T, MyAlloc<T>>; // Как и ранее

template<typename T>
class Widget {
private:
    MyAllocList<T> list;                      // Ни typename,
    …                                         // ни ::type
};
```

Для вас `MyAllocList<T>` (т.е. использование шаблона псевдонима) может выглядеть как зависимый от параметра шаблона `T`, как и `MyAllocList<T>::type` (т.е. как и использование вложенного `typedef`), но вы не компилятор. Когда компилятор обрабатывает шаблон `Widget` и встречает использование `MyAllocList<T>` (т.е. использование шаблона псевдонима), он знает, что `MyAllocList<T>` является именем типа, поскольку `MyAllocList` является шаблоном псевдонима: он обязан быть именем типа. Тем самым `MyAllocList<T>` оказывается независимым типом, и спецификатор `typename` не является ни требуемым, ни разрешенным.

С другой стороны, когда компилятор видит `MyAllocList<T>::type` (т.е. использование вложенных `typedef`) в шаблоне `Widget`, он не может знать наверняка, что эта конструкция именует тип, поскольку это может быть специализация `MyAllocList`, с которой он еще не встречался и в которой `MyAllocList<T>::type` ссылается на нечто, отличное от типа. Это звучит глупо, но не вините компиляторы за то, что они рассматривают такую возможность. В конце концов, это люди пишут такой код.
Например, некая заблудшая душа вполне в состоянии написать следующее:

```
class Wine { … };

template<>                // Специализация MyAllocList в
class MyAllocList<Wine> { // которой T представляет собой Wine
private:
    enum class WineType   // См. в разделе 3.4 информацию об
    { White, Red, Rose }; // "enum class"

    WineType type;        // В этом классе type представляет
    …                     // собой данные-член!
};
```

Как видите, `MyAllocList<Wine>::type` не является типом. Если `Widget` инстанцирован с `Wine`, `MyAllocList<T>::type` в шаблоне `Widget` представляет собой данные-член, а не тип. Ссылается ли `MyAllocList<T>::type` на тип в шаблоне `Widget`, зависит от того, чем является `T`, а потому компиляторы требуют, чтобы вы точно указывали, что это тип, предваряя его ключевым словом `typename`.